# Unwanted Vertical Padding from iOS 6 on CATextLayer

Tags: ios, ipad, ios6, layer, catextlayer

**Background:** I started my project in iOS 5 and built out a beautiful button with layer. I added a textLayer onto the button and center it using the following code:

```
    float textLayerVerticlePadding = ((self.bounds.size.height - fontSize) /2);
    textLayer = [[CATextLayer alloc]init];
    [textLayer setFrame:CGRectOffset(self.bounds, 0, textLayerVerticlePadding)];
```

It works great and looks dead center until iOS 6.

**Problem:** iOS 6 added a space (padding) between the topmost bound and the text in textLayer. This upsets the calculation above. Is there a way to make sure that iOS 6 does not? because I would like to support both iOS 5 and 6 (for those who prefers Google Map).

**Pictures:**
This one is iOS 5 and the red color is the background of the textLayer (to make it more apparent)
[image]

And this one is iOS 6
[image]

---

**Update:** While im sure all the answers below are correct in their own ways, I found the post by t0rst simplest way to execute this. `HelveticaNeue` leaves a little space for both iOS5 and iOS6, unlike `Helvetica` which leaves no space on the top in iOS5 and little space in iOS6.

**Update 2:** Played around with it a little more, and found out the size of the little space. Without going into detail, the space is 1/6 of your font size. So to compensate for it I wrote

```
float textLayerVerticlePadding = ((self.bounds.size.height - fontSize) /2) - (fontSize/6);
[textLayer setFrame:CGRectOffset(self.bounds, 0, textLayerVerticlePadding)];
```

With that code, I get a dead center every time. Note that this is only tested with `HelveticaNeue-Bold` on iOS5 and iOS6. I cannot say for anything else.

Comment: Quick answer: use HelveticaNeue family in place of the system fonts (which is has font name ".HelveticaNeueUI"). Long answer: see below.

Comment: Hello, what if I want to add more padding to the top to make the HELLO in the center of the red box, ie vertical align = center?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In iOS 5 and before, the first baseline in a `CATextLayer` is always positioned down from the top of the bounds by the ascent obtained from `CTLineGetTypographicBounds` when passed a `CTLine` made with the string for the first line.

In iOS 6, this doesn't hold true for all fonts anymore. Hence, when you are positioning a `CATextLayer` you can no longer reliably decide where to put it to get the right visual alignment. Or can you? ...

First, an aside: when trying to work out `CATextLayer`'s positioning behaviour a while ago in iOS 5, I tried using all combinations of cap height, ascender from UIFont, etc. before finally discovering that ascent from `CTLineGetTypographicBounds` was the one I needed. In the process, I discovered that a) the ascent from `UIFont ascender`, `CTFontGetAscent` and `CTLineGetTypographicBounds` are inconsistent for certain typefaces, and b) the ascent is frequently strange - either cropping the accents or leaving way to much space above. The solution to a) is to know which value to use. There isn't really a solution to b) other than to leave plenty of room above by offsetting `CATextLayer` bounds if it likely you will have accents that get clipped.

Back to iOS 6. If you avoid the worst offending typefaces (as of 6.0, and probably subject to change), you can still do programatic positioning of `CATextLayer` with the rest of the typefaces. The offenders are: **AcademyEngravedLetPlain**, **Courier**, **HoeflerText** and **Palatino** - visually, these families position correctly (i.e. without clipping) in `CATextLayer`, but none of the three ascent sources gives you a usable indication of where the baseline is placed. **Helvetica** and **.HelveticaNeueUI** (aka system font) families position correctly with baseline at the ascent given by `UIFont ascender`, but the other ascent sources are not of use.

Some examples from tests I did. The sample text is drawn three times in different colours. The coordinate origin is top left of grey box. Black text is drawn by `CTLineDraw` offset downwards by the ascent from `CTLineGetTypographicBounds`; transparent red is drawn by `CATextLayer` with bounds equal to the grey box; transparent blue is drawn with the `UIKit` `NSString` addition `drawAtPoint:withFont:` locating at the origin of the grey box and with the `UIFont`.

1) A well behaved font, Copperplate-Light. The three samples are coincident, giving maroon, and meaning that the ascents are near enough the same from all sources. Same for iOS 5 and 6.

[image: copperplate-light iOS 6]

2) **Courier** under iOS 5. `CATextLayer` positions text too high (red), but `CTLineDraw` with ascent from `CTLineGetTypographicBounds` (black) matches `CATextLayer` positioning - so we can place and correct from there. `NSString drawAtPoint:withFont:` (blue) places the text without clipping. (**Helvetica** and **.HelveticaNeueUI** behave like this in iOS 6)

[image: courier iOS 5]

3) **Courier** under iOS 6. `CATextLayer` (red) now places the text so that it is not clipped, but the positioning no longer matches the ascent from `CTLineGetTypographicBounds` (black) or from `UIFont` ascender used in `NSString drawAtPoint:withFont:` (blue). This is unusable for programatic positioning. (**AcademyEngravedLetPlain**, **HoeflerText** and **Palatino** also behave like this in iOS 6)

[image: courier iOS 6]

Hope this helps avoid some of the hours of wasted time I went through, and if you want to dip in a bit deeper, have a play with this:

```
- (NSString*)reportInconsistentFontAscents
{
    NSMutableString*            results;
    NSMutableArray*             fontNameArray;
    CGFloat                     fontSize = 28;
    NSString*                   fn;
    NSString*                   sample = @"Éa3Çy";
    CFRange                     range;
    NSMutableAttributedString*  mas;
    UIFont*                     uifont;
    CTFontRef                   ctfont;
    CTLineRef                   ctline;
    CGFloat                     uif_ascent;
    CGFloat                     ctfont_ascent;
    CGFloat                     ctline_ascent;

    results = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity: 10000];
    mas = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString: sample];
    range.location = 0, range.length = [sample length];

    fontNameArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity: 250];
    for (fn in [UIFont familyNames])
        [fontNameArray addObjectsFromArray: [UIFont fontNamesForFamilyName: fn]];
    [fontNameArray sortUsingSelector: @selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];
    [fontNameArray addObject: [UIFont systemFontOfSize: fontSize].fontName];
    [fontNameArray addObject: [UIFont italicSystemFontOfSize: fontSize].fontName];
    [fontNameArray addObject: [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize: fontSize].fontName];

    [results appendString: @"Font name\tUIFA\tCTFA\tCTLA"];

    for (fn in fontNameArray)
    {
        uifont = [UIFont fontWithName: fn size: fontSize];
        uif_ascent = uifont.ascender;

        ctfont = CTFontCreateWithName((CFStringRef)fn, fontSize, NULL);
        ctfont_ascent = CTFontGetAscent(ctfont);

        CFAttributedStringSetAttribute((CFMutableAttributedStringRef)mas, range, kCTFontAttributeName, ctfont);
        ctline = CTLineCreateWithAttributedString((CFAttributedStringRef)mas);
        ctline_ascent = 0;
        CTLineGetTypographicBounds(ctline, &ctline_ascent, 0, 0);

        [results appendFormat: @"\n%@\t%.3f\t%.3f\t%.3f", fn, uif_ascent, ctfont_ascent, ctline_ascent];

        if (fabsf(uif_ascent - ctfont_ascent) >= .5f // >.5 can round to pixel diffs in display
         || fabsf(uif_ascent - ctline_ascent) >= .5f)
            [results appendString: @"\t*****"];

        CFRelease(ctline);
        CFRelease(ctfont);
    }

    [mas release];

    return results;
}
```

Comment: Hello, is it possible to vertical align center Hello in the red box?

Comment: @VanDuTran The answer above is all about predicting (as reliably as is possible) the vertical position of the baseline of your text when your CATextLayer.bounds.origin is 0,0. Once you know this, you can work out where you actually want the baseline to be positioned (using the font’s cap height, ascent, your available area, etc.) for the effect you want to achieve, and then you adjust CATextLayer.bounds.origin.y to offset the baseline to the right position.

Comment: I will try, because in my case, I want the red box to be visible as a background to the text layer. So i want white text in middle of a red box.

Comment: How does this help to center text inside CATextLayer? I don't get it

Comment: @spail If your display is static, just adjust your size and position numbers manually until they are ok. If you have to position dynamically, then you need to know where CATextLayer places the baseline when you use a give UIFont in a given bounds, so that you can adjust sizes and offsets programatically for the desired effect. CATextLayer does not tell you where it puts the baseline. This answer is about how to predict, with as much reliability as we can manage, where CATextLayer will place the text. Once you know this, your programatic positioning can follow.

Comment: @t0rst ah, right, I was using wrong values. seems like to vertically center text inside layer you have to adjust it's bounds' origin.y by (textLayer.bounds.size.height - myFont.capHeight) / 2.0 - (myFont.ascender - myFont.capHeight) / 2.0

Answer (score 3):

t0rst's answer helps me. 
I think capHeight and xHeight are key.

```
    CATextLayer *mytextLayer = [CATextLayer layer];
    CGFloat fontSize = 30;
    UIFont *boldFont = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:fontSize];
    mytextLayer.font = (__bridge CFTypeRef)(boldFont.fontName);
    mytextLayer.fontSize = fontSize;

    CGFloat offsetY = 0;

    //if system version is grater than 6
    if(([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] compare:@"6" options:NSNumericSearch] == NSOrderedDescending)){
        offsetY = -(boldFont.capHeight - boldFont.xHeight);
    }

    //you have to set textX, textY, textWidth
    mytextLayer.frame = CGRectMake(textX, textY + offsetY, textWidth, fontSize);
```

Answer (score 1):

Wile I am waiting for an ultimate solution, I studied about RTLabel and TTTAttributedLabel, and made a simple class to draw text on a CALayer as Steve suggested. Hope it helps, and please don't hesitant to point out any mistake I have made.

CustomTextLayer.h

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

@interface CustomTextLayer : CALayer {
    NSString                        *_text;
    UIColor                         *_textColor;

    NSString                        *_font;
    float                           _fontSize;

    UIColor                         *_strokeColor;
    float                           _strokeWidth;

    CTTextAlignment                 _textAlignment;
    int                             _lineBreakMode;

    float                           _suggestHeight;
}

-(float) suggestedHeightForWidth:(float) width;

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *text;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIColor *textColor;

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *font;
@property (nonatomic, assign) float fontSize;

@property (nonatomic, retain) UIColor *strokeColor;
@property (nonatomic, assign) float strokeWidth;

@property (nonatomic, assign) CTTextAlignment textAlignment;

@end
```

CustomTextLayer.m

```
#import <CoreText/CoreText.h>
#import "CustomTextLayer.h"

@implementation CustomTextLayer

@synthesize text = _text, textColor = _textColor;
@synthesize font = _font, fontSize = _fontSize;
@synthesize strokeColor = _strokeColor, strokeWidth = _strokeWidth;
@synthesize textAlignment = _textAlignment;

-(id) init {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        _text = @"";
        _textColor = [UIColor blackColor];

        _font = @"Helvetica";
        _fontSize = 12;

        _strokeColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        _strokeWidth = 0.0;

        _textAlignment = kCTLeftTextAlignment;
        _lineBreakMode = kCTLineBreakByWordWrapping;

    }
    return self;
}

-(void) dealloc {
    [_text release];
    [_textColor release];

    [_font release];

    [_strokeColor release];

    [super dealloc];
}

-(void) setText:(NSString *)text {
    [_text release];
    _text = [text retain];
    [self setNeedsDisplay];
}

-(void) setTextColor:(UIColor *)textColor {
    [_textColor release];
    _textColor = [textColor retain];
    [self setNeedsDisplay];
}

-(void) setFont:(NSString *)font {
    [_font release];
    _font = [font retain];
    [self setNeedsDisplay];
}

-(void) setFontSize:(float)fontSize {
    _fontSize = fontSize;
    [self setNeedsDisplay];
}

-(void) setStrokeColor:(UIColor *)strokeColor {
    [_strokeColor release];
    _strokeColor = strokeColor;
    [self setNeedsDisplay];
}

-(void) setStrokeWidth:(float)strokeWidth {
    _strokeWidth = 0 ? (strokeWidth < 0) : (-1 * strokeWidth);
    [self setNeedsDisplay];
}

-(void) setTextAlignment:(CTTextAlignment)textAlignment {
    _textAlignment = textAlignment;
    [self setNeedsDisplay];
}

-(void) setFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    [super setFrame: frame];
    [self setNeedsDisplay];
}

-(float) suggestedHeightForWidth:(float) width {

    CTFontRef fontRef = CTFontCreateWithName((CFStringRef)_font, _fontSize, NULL);

    CTParagraphStyleSetting paragraphStyles[2] = {
        {.spec = kCTParagraphStyleSpecifierLineBreakMode, .valueSize = sizeof(CTLineBreakMode), .value = (const void *) &_lineBreakMode},
        {.spec = kCTParagraphStyleSpecifierAlignment, .valueSize = sizeof(CTTextAlignment), .value = (const void *) &_textAlignment}
    };
    CTParagraphStyleRef paragraphStyle = CTParagraphStyleCreate(paragraphStyles, 2);

    NSDictionary *attrDict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:(id)fontRef, (NSString *)kCTFontAttributeName, (id)_textColor.CGColor, (NSString *)(kCTForegroundColorAttributeName), (id)_strokeColor.CGColor, (NSString *)(kCTStrokeColorAttributeName), (id)[NSNumber numberWithFloat: _strokeWidth], (NSString *)(kCTStrokeWidthAttributeName), (id)paragraphStyle, (NSString *)(kCTParagraphStyleAttributeName), nil];

    CFRelease(fontRef);
    CFRelease(paragraphStyle);

    NSAttributedString *attrStr = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:_text attributes: attrDict];

    // Determine suggested frame height
    CFRange textRange = CFRangeMake(0, [attrStr length]);
    CGSize constraint = CGSizeMake(width, 9999);

    CTFramesetterRef framesetter = CTFramesetterCreateWithAttributedString((CFAttributedStringRef)attrStr);
    CGSize textSize = CTFramesetterSuggestFrameSizeWithConstraints(framesetter, textRange, NULL, constraint, NULL);
    textSize = CGSizeMake(ceilf(textSize.width), ceilf(textSize.height));

    [attrDict release];
    [attrStr release];

    return textSize.height;
}

-(void) renderText:(CGContextRef)ctx {
    CGContextSetTextMatrix(ctx, CGAffineTransformIdentity);
    CGContextTranslateCTM(ctx, 0, self.bounds.size.height);
    CGContextScaleCTM(ctx, 1.0, -1.0);

    CTFontRef fontRef = CTFontCreateWithName((CFStringRef)_font, _fontSize, NULL);

    CTParagraphStyleSetting paragraphStyles[2] = {
        {.spec = kCTParagraphStyleSpecifierLineBreakMode, .valueSize = sizeof(CTLineBreakMode), .value = (const void *) &_lineBreakMode},
        {.spec = kCTParagraphStyleSpecifierAlignment, .valueSize = sizeof(CTTextAlignment), .value = (const void *) &_textAlignment}
    };
    CTParagraphStyleRef paragraphStyle = CTParagraphStyleCreate(paragraphStyles, 2);

    NSDictionary *attrDict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:(id)fontRef, (NSString *)kCTFontAttributeName, (id)_textColor.CGColor, (NSString *)(kCTForegroundColorAttributeName), (id)_strokeColor.CGColor, (NSString *)(kCTStrokeColorAttributeName), (id)[NSNumber numberWithFloat: _strokeWidth], (NSString *)(kCTStrokeWidthAttributeName), (id)paragraphStyle, (NSString *)(kCTParagraphStyleAttributeName), nil];

    CFRelease(fontRef);
    CFRelease(paragraphStyle);

    NSAttributedString *attrStr = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:_text attributes: attrDict];

    CGMutablePathRef path = CGPathCreateMutable();
    CGPathAddRect(path, NULL, self.bounds);
    CTFramesetterRef framesetter = CTFramesetterCreateWithAttributedString((CFAttributedStringRef)attrStr);

    CFRange textRange = CFRangeMake(0, [attrStr length]);
    CTFrameRef frame = CTFramesetterCreateFrame(framesetter, textRange, path, NULL);
    CFArrayRef lines = CTFrameGetLines(frame);
    NSInteger numberOfLines = CFArrayGetCount(lines);
    CGPoint lineOrigins[numberOfLines];
    CTFrameGetLineOrigins(frame, CFRangeMake(0, numberOfLines), lineOrigins);

    for (CFIndex lineIndex = 0; lineIndex < numberOfLines; lineIndex++) {
        CGPoint lineOrigin = lineOrigins[lineIndex];
        CGContextSetTextPosition(ctx, lineOrigin.x,  lineOrigin.y);
        CTLineRef line = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(lines, lineIndex);

        if (lineIndex == numberOfLines - 1) {
            CFRange lastLineRange = CTLineGetStringRange(line);

            if (!(lastLineRange.length == 0 && lastLineRange.location == 0) && lastLineRange.location + lastLineRange.length < textRange.location + textRange.length) {
                NSUInteger truncationAttributePosition = lastLineRange.location;
                CTLineTruncationType truncationType;
                if (numberOfLines != 1) {
                    truncationType = kCTLineTruncationEnd;
                    truncationAttributePosition += (lastLineRange.length - 1);
                }

                NSAttributedString *tokenString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"\u2026" attributes:attrDict];
                CTLineRef truncationToken = CTLineCreateWithAttributedString((CFAttributedStringRef)tokenString);

                NSMutableAttributedString *truncationString = [[attrStr attributedSubstringFromRange: NSMakeRange(lastLineRange.location, lastLineRange.length)] mutableCopy];
                if (lastLineRange.length > 0) {
                    unichar lastCharacter = [[truncationString string] characterAtIndex: lastLineRange.length - 1];
                    if ([[NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet] characterIsMember:lastCharacter]) {
                        [truncationString deleteCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(lastLineRange.length - 1, 1)];
                    }
                }
                [truncationString appendAttributedString: tokenString];
                CTLineRef truncationLine = CTLineCreateWithAttributedString((CFAttributedStringRef) truncationString);

                CTLineRef truncatedLine = CTLineCreateTruncatedLine(truncationLine, self.bounds.size.width, truncationType, truncationToken);
                if (!truncatedLine) {
                    // If the line is not as wide as the truncationToken, truncatedLine is NULL
                    truncatedLine = CFRetain(truncationToken);
                }

                CTLineDraw(truncatedLine, ctx);

                CFRelease(truncatedLine);
                CFRelease(truncationLine);
                CFRelease(truncationToken);
            } else {
                CTLineDraw(line, ctx);
            }
        } else {
            CTLineDraw(line, ctx);
        }
    }

    [attrStr release];
    [attrDict release];

    CFRelease(path);
    CFRelease(frame);
    CFRelease(framesetter);

}

-(void) drawInContext:(CGContextRef)ctx {
    [super drawInContext: ctx];
    [self renderText: ctx];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

I think to support both you can create a category for text layers, in category you can code it conditionally for both versions. 
Same as we do for navigation bar when we change image.

You can center your frame as you did with different frames for different ios versions

Comment: While this is a valid answer and definitely would work, I hope to see a more robust way of solving this. Conditioning is rather hackerish in my book. Thanks for your effort.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that iOS 6 has taken into account the Line Height (or other font related features that affects the actual vertical drawing position of the glyph) of the font when drawing the text contents of CATextLayer. The result is that in iOS 6.0, the text with certain font in CATextLayer is not displayed at the top edge of the frame of the CATextLayer. I found that some font has such vertical padding while others don't. While in iOS 5.0/5.1, the glyph of the text is actually displayed at the top edge of the frame of the CATextLayer.

So one possible solution I'm thinking may be to change the textLayer object in your code from CATextLayer to just CALayer (or subclass CALayer) and use Core Text to custom draw the contents such that you get to control of everything that will be consistent across iOS 5.0/5.1 and 6.0.