# Vertically aligning text in an NSTextField using Swift

Tags: swift, cocoa, appkit

I have been reading through the various options on how to set the vertical alignment on an NSTextField. I want the text to be displayed in the center and to do it programatically in Swift. Here are the things I have looked so far:

- http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/174994-repositioning-an-nstextfieldcell.html
- https://red-sweater.com/blog/148/what-a-difference-a-cell-makes
- [Vertically Centre Text in NSSecureTextField with subclassing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9400686/vertically-centre-text-in-nssecuretextfield-with-subclassing)
- [Get NSTextField contents to scale](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2908704/get-nstextfield-contents-to-scale)
- [vertically align text in a CATextLayer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4765461/vertically-align-text-in-a-catextlayer/32462462#32462462)

One thing I have tried in Swift is to set the following property:

```
textField.usesSingleLineMode = true
```

Any tips on the best way to vertically center text would be much appreciated!

Comment: link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1235219/is-there-a-right-way-to-have-nstextfieldcell-draw-vertically-centered-text

Answer (score 8):

This is very hard to do, as Apple makes this very difficult. I achieved it by subclassing NSTextFieldCell and overriding the drawingRectForBounds: method like so:

```
override func drawingRectForBounds(theRect: NSRect) -> NSRect {
    let newRect = NSRect(x: 0, y: (theRect.size.height - 22) / 2, width: theRect.size.width, height: 22)
    return super.drawingRectForBounds(newRect)
}
```

This is just my way to do it, I'm sure there are better ways, which I don't know (yet). And this only works for the standard font size in TextFields (which gives a text height of 22). That's why I hardcoded that. Haven't figured out yet, how to get the height in the cell if you change the font.

Result:

[image]

Comment: What else you can do is to add an NSTextField with no border to an NSView as a subview. :)

Comment: [NSLayoutManager defaultLineHeightForFont:]

Comment: Where does `22` come from?

Comment: Thats the font size of textviews

Answer (score 4):

Try this on a playground, it centers the text perfectly, use it on your projects! Hope it helps!

```
import Cocoa

let cell = NSTableCellView()
cell.frame = NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100)
let tf = NSTextField()
tf.frame = cell.frame
tf.stringValue = "MyTextfield"
tf.alignment = .Center

let stringHeight: CGFloat = tf.attributedStringValue.size().height
let frame = tf.frame
var titleRect:  NSRect = tf.cell!.titleRectForBounds(frame)

titleRect.size.height = stringHeight + ( stringHeight - (tf.font!.ascender + tf.font!.descender ) )
titleRect.origin.y = frame.size.height / 2  - tf.lastBaselineOffsetFromBottom - tf.font!.xHeight / 2
tf.frame = titleRect
cell.addSubview(tf)
```

Answer (score 3):

The accepted answer works perfectly and here's the Swift3 version.

```
class VerticallyAlignedTextFieldCell: NSTextFieldCell {
    override func drawingRect(forBounds rect: NSRect) -> NSRect {
        let newRect = NSRect(x: 0, y: (rect.size.height - 22) / 2, width: rect.size.width, height: 22)
        return super.drawingRect(forBounds: newRect)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I have added the NSTextField inside a NSView and centered it.

Another solution was (in an iOS project) to create a UILabel and allow it adjust its size (sizeToFit()) and again embed it inside a UIView.

I personally don't like the calculations in previous answers and the second solution for iOS works for all texts size and row numbers.

Answer (score 3):

I was also facing vertical alignment issue with NSTextField. My requirement involved, rendering a single-line string inside a NSTextField. Additionally,
textfield needed to be resize implying we had programatically resized the font-point-size of the text inside text-field on resize. In this scenario we faced vertical-alignment issues - the mis-alignment was tough to grasp/understand in a straight forward way.

*What finally worked:*

So, in my scenario a simple,
 **turn off the "Single Line Mode" in interface builder**
for the text-field solved the issue.

Comment: That’s what worked for me, too. None of the suggested subclassing approaches worked quite right—text was sometimes clipped.

Answer (score 0):

For a single-line textfield, turning off the border worked for me.

```
tf.isBordered = false
```

I also include these, but turning off the border was critical.

```
tf.maximumNumberOfLines = 1
tf.drawsBackground = false
tf.isEditable = false
tf.usesSingleLineMode = true
```