# How to adjust vertically single line string in NSTextField?

Tags: swift, nstextfield

I am using custom font for non-editable NSTextField, which I created in StoryBoard:

```
generalDisplay.font = NSFont(name: "DS-Digital Bold", size: 25.0)
```

Then I am adjusting frame height:

```
generalDisplay.frame.size.height = 28
```

The result is not centered vertically:

[image]

I've tried to turn off single line mode, but the result is even worse.

[image]

If I should subclass it, could you give me an example what methods I have to override?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Vertically aligning text in an NSTextField using Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34379353/vertically-aligning-text-in-an-nstextfield-using-swift)

Answer (score 0):

You can subclass UITextField and override this method:

```
override func textRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect { 
   return bounds.inset(by: UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 5, bottom: 0, right: 10)) 
}
```

Comment: It is not for iOS, but `NSTextField`.

Comment: You're right, I read Swift and textfield and completely misunderstood

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the Apple documentation for NSTextfield maybe you could [initialize your `NSTextField` with a `NSAttributedString`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nstextfield/1644658-init) to be able to change the baseline

```swift
NSTextfield(labelWithAttributedString: NSAttributedString)
```

Comment: `Use of unresolved identifier 'NSBaselineOffsetAttributeName'`, `Value of type 'NSTextField' has no member 'defaultTextAttributes'`

Comment: Just read your comment on the other answer thought this was for iOS swift and confused it with `UITextfield` but maybe this can help since it talks about baseline offsets here as well https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/TextUILayer/Tasks/SetTextAttributes.html

Comment: After reading the documentation I updated my answer, maybe it would work, I don't really know the context to be able to narrow down the search myself but if it doesn't help hope someone else will have better knowledge of `NSTextfield`

Comment: `let atrString = NSMutableAttributedString()
                atrString.append(NSAttributedString(string: display.data, attributes: [NSAttributedStringKey.baselineOffset:15.0]))
                generalDisplay.attributedStringValue = atrString` doesn't move offset inside text field...

Comment: Setting field to single line mode moves to base offset. But I wonder if the offset can be calculated based on font size.

Comment: You could probably subclass NSAttributedString so that it would recalculate the offset after setting the font or the font size